# Let $A=\{1,2,3..,9\}$. How many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 2$ and f is onto?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

To clarify, A is set containing 9 elements (1-9). To tackle the problem, I first count

> How many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 2$?

To which the answer I got is  $8 \cdot 1 \cdot  9^7$

Then to get

> How many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 2$ and f is onto?

what I would do is  $8 \cdot  1 \cdot  9^7$ - not onto functions.

I'm not 100% sure how many not onto functions are there given $(f\circ f)(1) = 2$. I want to say $7!$ not onto functions then the answer is $8 \cdot  1 \cdot  9^7$ - $7!$

Would this be correct?

Also with some help from here, I tried counting the number functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 2$ and f is onto directly to which I got the answer as $7\cdot 1\cdot 7!$

I am not sure which would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. If $f \circ f (1)=2$  then 
$f(1)=k$ and  $f(k)=2$ for some $k\in \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ ($k=1$ is not allowed otherwise $f \circ f (1)=1$). Note that in order to be onto, $f$ should be bijective (hence $f(1)\not=2$ otherwise $f(1)=f(k)=2$ and $f$ is not injective).

Comment: right if $f(1) = 1$ then $f(f(1)) = 1$ which contradicts the condition $f(f(1)) = 2$. And $f(1) =/= 2$ because that contradicts the onto requirement. Thats how I got my second answer. basically step 1 choose image of f(1) (but not 1 or 2) giving 7 choices. choose the f(f(1)) as 2 which has 1 choice. then choose the remains images f(2-9) satisfying the onto requirement each time, giving $7!$. leading to $7*1*7!$

Comment: So just for kicks, if the question was simply how many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $f(1) = 2$ and $f$ is onto (ignoring the composition requirement), the answer would be 8!?

Comment: @Omar Yes. that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

If $f:\>[9]\to[9]$ is onto then it is bijective. It is easy to see that $f(1)=1$ and $f(1)=2$ both are impossible. Therefore $f(1)=k\in\{3,4,\ldots,9\}$, and $f(k)=2$. We can choose $k$ in $7$ ways and the rest of $f$ in $(9-2)!=5040$ ways. The total number of such functions therefore is $7\cdot5040=35\,280$.